# When backspace is pressed, delete the key or the li

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made the next jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alonshmiel/Sq5wa/4/

when the user press the `backspace` key, I want to delete by the next instructions:

1. if the desired char to delete is a character, delete it.
2. if the desired char is `<li>` element: delete the `<li>` and delete a `<div>` element that is found in "countries" `<ul>`: `<div><br></div>` (every `<li>` creates `<div><br></div>`)

I have a function that detects the backspace key:

```
$('#countries').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 8) {

    }
});
```

you can add li-s by add text to the ul and press the enter key

any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with this line :

```
$(window.getSelection().anchorNode).closest('li').remove();
```

It will get the current cursor position and delete the node if it is a `li`.